# Selecting without replacement a subset of items from a set knowing the final probabilities that items will be chosen

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I don’t know if my title makes sense so I will try to explain using basketball as an analogy.

Say you have a set of players and you know the probabilities of them being on court at a given moment. There always needs to be a fixed number on court at once, and the player probabilities are generally different to each other. How then would you then calculate the probability of a specific line-up being formed given this information? The problem sounds like it should be simple but I don’t know the right way to approach it.

Take the trivial case of selecting a 2 man line-up from a set of 3 players (A, B, C) with probabilities (0.9, 0.8, 0.3). The line-up probabilities would then be (AB=0.7, AC=0.2, BC=0.1), which doesn’t seem very intuitive.

Then for another example, imagine you had another person to pick from, so you now have to pick 2 out of a set of 4. Say that the player probabilities are now (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), this would make the line-up probabilities (AB=1/6, AC=1/6, …). If you change the player probabilities to (0.5, 0.5, 1, 0), then the new line-up probabilities would be (AB=0, AC=1/2, ...).

Is there a formula for this, because I’m really at a loss of how to approach this.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out is that this problem does not have a unique solution, unless you make some additional assumptions. If there are $n$ players to choose from and $k$ players in a lineup, you have $n-1$ equations (the player probabilities, which must sum to 1) in ${n \choose k}-1$ unknowns (the lineup probabilities, which also sum to 1).

Comment: Thanks for reading, I don’t think I was able to explain this very clearly. What I called the “player probabilities” actually sum to k (the number of players in a lineup), and represent the probability they will be on court (or the sum of lineup probabilities which they are present).
Unless I’m missing something this would have to have a unique solution?

Comment: Sorry, I meant sum to k, not sum to 1. Consider the case where the player probabilities are (0.6,0.6,0.4,0.4). You can have (AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD) = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0) or (0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4) or any number of solutions. This is because you're trying to work out 5 lineup probabilities (the last one is 1 minus the sum of the others) from 3 player probabilities (the last one is 2 minus the sum of the others).

Comment: Ah thanks, I get it now. I wasn’t really thinking about it as a system of linear equations, just kind of hoping there would be some fancy conditional probability formula or something. Thanks for your time.